# Mock imported class in typescript with jest

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

I am trying to use jest to mock an imported class inside a typescript class, the following code is used for the main program(I removed some code from inside the functions but it shoud still be clear what I am trying to do)

```
import * as SocketIO from "socket.io";

import {AuthenticatedDao} from "../../dao/authenticated.dao";

export default class AuthenticationService {
    private readonly _authenticatedDao: AuthenticatedDao = AuthenticatedDao.Instance;
    private readonly _io;

    constructor(socketIo: SocketIO.Server) {
        this._io = socketIo;
    }

    public authenticateUser(username: string, password: string, clientSocketId: string): void {
        this._authenticatedDao.authenticateUser(username, password).then((authenticatedUser) => {

        }).catch(rejected => {

        });
    }
}


import {createServer, Server} from 'http';
import * as express from 'express';
import * as socketIo from 'socket.io';
import {LogincredentialsDto} from "./models/dto/logincredentials.dto";
import {config} from './config/config';
import AuthenticationService from "./services/implementation/authentication.service";
import {Logger} from "./helperclasses/logger";
import {format} from "util";

export class ClassA {
    private readonly _configPort = config.socketServerPort;

    private readonly _logger: Logger = Logger.Instance;
    private _app: express.Application;
    private _server: Server;
    private _io: socketIo.Server;
    private _socketServerPort: string | number;
    private _authenticationService: AuthenticationService;


    constructor() {
        this.configure();
        this.socketListener();
    }

    private configure(): void {
        this._app = express();

        //this._server = createServer(config.sslCredentials, this._app);
        this._server = createServer(this._app);

        this._socketServerPort = process.env.PORT || this._configPort;
        this._io = socketIo(this._server);

        this._server.listen(this._socketServerPort, () => {
            this._logger.log(format('Server is running on port: %s', this._socketServerPort));
        });

        this._authenticationService = new AuthenticationService(this._io);
    }


    private socketListener(): void {
        this._io.on('connection', (client) => {
                client.on('authenticate', (loginCreds: LogincredentialsDto) => {
                    console.log(loginCreds.username, loginCreds.password, client.id);
                    this._authenticationService.authenticateUser(loginCreds.username, loginCreds.password, client.id);
                });
            }
        );
    }
}
```

I am trying to mock the function "authenticateUser" in "AuthenticationService", instead of calling the normal code I want to mock the promise. I tried using the examples provided in https://jestjs.io/docs/en/es6-class-mocks but when I try doing the following:

```
import AuthenticationService from '../src/services/implementation/authentication.service';
jest.mock('./services/implementation/authentication.service');

beforeEach(() => {
    AuthenticationService.mockClear();
});

it('test', () => {

    // mock.instances is available with automatic mocks:
    const authServerInstance = AuthenticationService.mock.instances[0];
```

I get this error:
    Error:(62, 31) TS2339: Property 'mock' does not exist on type 'typeof AuthenticationService'.

What am I doing wrong here? Should I be mocking the class/function differently since it's using promises?

Comment: that error is a TypeScript typing error.  can you share your test code?

Comment: Hi Brian, 

I added a small snippet of the test code, but the issue is I can't run the test because I can't mock the class.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

### Issue

The typing for `AuthenticationService` does not include the `mock` property so TypeScript throws an error.

---

### Details

`jest.mock` creates an [automatic mock](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/es6-class-mocks#automatic-mock) of the module which "replaces the ES6 class with a mock constructor, and replaces all of its methods with mock functions that always return `undefined`".

In this case the `default` export of `authentication.service.ts` is an ES6 class so it is replaced with a mock constructor.

The mock constructor has a `mock` property but TypeScript doesn't know about it and is still treating `AuthenticationService` as the original type.

---

### Solution

Use `jest.Mocked` to let TypeScript know about the typing changes caused by `jest.mock`:

```ts
import * as original from './services/implementation/authentication.service';  // import module
jest.mock('./services/implementation/authentication.service');

const mocked = original as jest.Mocked<typeof original>;  // Let TypeScript know mocked is an auto-mock of the module
const AuthenticationService = mocked.default;  // AuthenticationService has correct TypeScript typing

beforeEach(() => {
  AuthenticationService.mockClear();
});

it('test', () => {

    // mock.instances is available with automatic mocks:
    const authServerInstance = AuthenticationService.mock.instances[0];
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, by using your code I figured out how to mock a function within a class, thanks for including the details as well, it makes it more clear now.

Comment: @brian-lives-outdoors I tried this but for some reason typescript still looks at the Mocked instance as the actual type it is mocking... any ideas? (trying to mock an interface)

Comment: This actually doesn't work for me because TypeScript is telling me I need to cast it to unknown first. i.e. `original as unknown as jest.Mocked<typeof original>` Does anyone know a way around this?

Comment: This isn't working for me. AuthenticationService.mockClear(); produces -> property mockClear does not exist in bla bla. Inspecting the object it have mockClear, mock, etc. But the types are not known to typescript.

Comment: I had to replace `const AuthenticationService = mocked.default;` with `const AuthenticationService = mocked.AuthenticationService`, then it worked for me. I'm using ts-jest 25.2.1.

Comment: TS2339: Property 'default' does not exist on type 'Mocked '.

Comment: Property 'Mocked' does not exist on type 'typeof jest'. Did you mean 'mocked'?ts(2551)

Comment: Thanks Brian Adams, it worked fine for me!